# Error connecting HANA with Python, SQL syntax error:

Tags: python, hana

I have an error when connecting to the hanna sap database from Python, below is the code from sap.py

```
import pyhdb
import hana_ml
import hana_ml.dataframe as dataframe
# Instantiate connection object
conn = dataframe.ConnectionContext("xxx.xxx.xx.x.", 30015, "der", "qwertt")

sql="SELECT T0.'firstName' FROM 'OHEM'.T0"

df_pushdown = conn.sql(sql)
print(df_pushdown.collect())

# Close connection
conn.close()
```

The problem is:

```
py sap.py
(257, 'sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "firstName": line 1 col 11 (at pos 11)')
Failed to retrieve data for the current dataframe, (257, 'sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "firstName": line 1 col 11 (at pos 11)')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jmoreira\Desktop\Proyectos\peso\sap.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(df_pushdown.collect())
  File "C:\Users\jmoreira\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\hana_ml\dataframe.py", line 2990, in collect
```

Comment: There's something wrong with your sql code, this isn't really a python issue.

Comment: I am not sure about HANA, but usually notation is 'string' and "column". So Try `SELECT T0."firstName" FROM "OHEM".T0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, it seems you mixed up double and single quotes.

Try this:

```
sql='SELECT T0."firstName" FROM "OHEM".T0'
```